# Loading the content of an xml file into an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to load the content of an xml file into an html element using the JQuery $.get(url, data, callback) method. 
Here is explicitly the code that I wrote:

```
function loadFileToElement(filename, elementId) {
    var path = filename + ".xml";
    var component = document.getElementById(elementId);

    try {
        $.get(path, 
              function(data) {
                    component.innerHTML = data;
        });

    } catch (e) {
        window.alert("Unable to load the requested file " + filename);
    }
}
```

This code works smoothly in IE, but not in Firefox and Google Chrome.
By debugging the loadFileToElement() method I figured out that the callback method was not executed.
Any Help ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If the callback isn't getting executed, then there must've been an error retrieving the file. Is this a local file? Are you running this on a web server, or are you running it off the local file system. I suspect Chrome is blocking you from accessing the local file system file via AJAX.

Comment: Yes, this is a local file and I´m running the  this on my local file system

Comment: Please [see this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy). This is the issue you are facing.